# How do I get the number of elements in a block?

Tags: ruby

I have two files `init.rb` and `airport.rb`.

How I can count the number of items matching the value?

init.rb:

```
airport1.airplanes_count { |a| a.aircraft_type == "Boeing 747" }
```

airport.rb:

```
def airplanes_count
  @airplanes.each  { |a|  a if yield(a)  }
end
```

If `aircraft_type` = Boeing 747, I need to get a number of aircraft:

```
=> 2
```

instead of aircraft name

```
=> #<Airplane:0x0000000155e348>
   #<Airplane:0x0000000155e028>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should look like this:

```
def airplanes_count
    @airplanes.count{ |a|  a if yield(a)  }
end
```

Comment: gabitzish +1

 def airplanes_count
  puts @airplanes.count{ |a| a if yield(a)  }
 end

Comment: ssory :D don't have reputation:) my first secodns on stackoverflow)))

Comment: This is good. But you can leave out the a if yield(a) ...and just have yield(a)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby already brings a [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) method on all Enumerators (like Hashes, Array, ...). You can "forward" your block like this:

```
def airplanes_count(&block)
  @airplanes.count(&block)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are much better ways to do this... but ... if you don't want to change too much code you can just change the body of airplanes_count to this line.

```
def airplanes_count
    @airplanes.inject(0)  { |count,a|  yield(a)?  (count + 1) : count  }
end
```

This will give you what you are looking for.